# Disadvantages of heavier armour

Tags: the-witcher-3

What are the disadvantages of heavier armour (other than the missed bonus from *cat/griffin school techniques* general abilities)?

Comment: I believe the heavier the armour the slower your stamina regens, meaning you'll not be able to use Signs as often as you would in light armour.

Comment: That's correct, @DavidYell. I'd mention that you'll get the Bear school technique bonus instead of the cat/griffin, too, so it's not so much missing as different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weight of your armour affects the rate at which your stamina regenerates.

So heavier armour, despite providing more damage resistance will prevent you using signs as frequently. Wearing lighter armour will not penalise your stamina regeneration, so you can use more signs.

Comment: Light armor not only doesn't penalize stam regen, it provides a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Armor weight class effects Stamina regen.

Light armor: bonus to stam regen
Medium/ no armor: normal stam regen
Heavy armor: penalty to stam regen

FWIW, the crafted armor sets have the same raw armor values at mastercrafted (save the wolf set, in that I don't know for sure that's true, not that it isn't true), so by level 30+ the question becomes which perk and corresponding armor set are best suited to your play style. You'll also have so much alcohol you'll be able to use tawny owl on cool down, so stamina ceases to be a concern.